# Jar file not playing mp3 whatsoever

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, mp3

I have this code that plays the music every time I run the program in intellij idea, but when I compile a jar (Build artifacts), sound does not play. I have tried changing the file path to ./ and many other things but I can't seem to figure this out. I am using Jlayer to play the mp3 files.

```
private void playSound() {

    try {
        InputStream fis = Jeopardy.class.getResourceAsStream("/audio/kahoot.mp3");
        Player playMP3 = new Player(fis);
        playMP3.play();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Failed to play the file.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: check the dependences when used in the jar and add them to your project